# MPI_Waitany() or MPI_Recv() with MPI_ANY_SOURCE?

Tags: mpi, hpc

Context:
In my program, the master process is allotting work for the slave processes. Once a slave process completes the work, it requests for more work from the master. Master allots more work to the slave and the program goes on.

I have written the program such a way that, the master process is using MPI_Recv with MPI_ANY_SOURCE for receiving work from the slave nodes.

```
/* Allot some work to all the slaves (seed) */

while (istheremorework()) {
            /* Master receives slaves work*/

            MPI_Status status;            
            MPI_Recv(recvbuf, width + 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            int slave = status.MPI_SOURCE;

            cout << "Master recieved data from slave " << slave << endl;
            /* store the data */    
            /* Master sends new work to the slave */
            int* sendbuf;
            /* populate sendbuf */
            MPI_Send(&sendbuf, 2, MPI_INT, slave, MSG_TAG_DATA, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            /* update remaining work information */;
}
```

This part of the code can also be rewritten as

```
/* Allot some work to all the slaves (seed) */

/* Open a channel with all the slaves to receive their work. */
for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
    MPI_Irecv(&recbuf[k], BUFFER_LENGTH, MPI_DOUBLE, k, MSG_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[k - 1]);
    /* Each slave sends the results to master */
}

while (istheremorework()) {
            /* Master receives slaves work*/         

            MPI_Waitany(np-1, requests, &index, statuses); 
            /* Using index to decide which slave sent the result */ 

            cout << "Master received data from slave " << slave << endl;
            /* store the data */    
            /* Master sends new work to the slave */
            int* sendbuf;
            /* populate sendbuf */
            MPI_Send(&sendbuf, 2, MPI_INT, slave, MSG_TAG_DATA, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            /* update remaining work information */;
}
```

Are these two methods equivalent to each other in terms of performance? Do you see any significant advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: In the second version, where `request` in `MPI_Waitany` is defined? Seems like you have `Irecv` before `MPI_Waitany` but you don't show.

Comment: @Shibli: Yes. You are right. In the second version, `Irecv` is there. After the initial allotment of work to the slaves, using 'Irecv' to open a channel for all the slaves to receive their work and using `MPI_Waitany` to consume one after the other. Please correct me, if my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Waitany version, you have to initialize and maintain an `MPI_Request` request object for each worker on the master process, and MPI will have to loop over all of them in the `MPI_Waitany()` call. With  `MPI_Recv(MPI_ANY_SOURCE)`, you simply process the next message from the message queue. I suspect the MPI_Recv version will be better.

You can try a performance profiler to be sure. For small to medium scales, there probably won't be much of a performance difference in this case. At large scale, however, it is considered a bad idea to allocate that many request objects simultaneously.